# How to prevent new line characters from interfering while converting input stream to xlsx (Excel) file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, multipart

I am converting a multipart file into an input stream and then further into an Excel workbook. But when I do it new line characters inside the cell are not getting converted properly and the cell value is different from what I intend.

I upload an excel file, that converts it into a multipart-file. I reconvert it into excel by first converting it into an input stream
I am not able to do it properly as string values containing newline character in the cell are not getting processed correctly. How do avoid this mistake?

```
public String bulkUploadHtml(MultipartFile multipartFile, String email) {
        String message = "*File is being processed. Upload status will be sent via email.";

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename())) {
        message = "Invalid file uploaded. Please try again.";
        LOG.error(message);
        return message;
    }
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
        String supc = cell.getStringCellValue();
        cell = row.getCell(1);
        String html = cell.getStringCellValue();
        LOG.info("SUPC + " + supc);
        LOG.info("HTML incoming + " + html);
        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        LOG.info("ERROR parsing excel html bulk upload file " + e.toString());

    }
    return null;
}
```

For example, if cell[0] has value "123\n456" only 123 comes when I access the value as cell.get(0).

Comment: Cannot reproducing this behavior. Sure this is not only a problem with your `Logger` which writes a string containing `"\n"` not the way as you think it should?

Comment: Thanks for checking it for me. Yes, it was a logging issue. Figured that out after putting a debug point.